# Can new wall go over tile floor?

Tags: walls, tile, remodeling

Looking at moving my laundry upstairs, and the right answer is to combine two adjacent closets to get the width and move one of their walls a foot or two into the kitchen to get the depth.

The kitchen floor is 10-inch-square tiles. It would be sort of nice if that continued on into the laundry closet. I do have a full bundle of spare tiles in the basement.

Question: Could/should I plan on the new wall coming in on top of the existing tiles (presumably having to drill to secure the footer without shattering them), or should I plan on removing the ones under the footer and fitting cut pieces back in afterward?

Comment: How about no cutting or drilling, use construction adhesive instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this all the time for partition walls. Tile the entire area then erect partition walls (usually metal studs) over the tile. Drill and screw at the grout joints for easy repair later. Way easier than cutting in tile and way easier to change later.

Comment: Ok, so I'm not completely crazy... Nice to have both dides heard from; I'm going to wait a while to see what the rest of the ckmmunity has to say.

Answer (score 12):

The "*correct*" way to do it, is to remove or cut the tile where the wall will go.  Whether or not you *want* to do that, is up to your personal preference.

Comment: +1 An angle grinder would give you the ability to cut out a strip of tiles where the new wall would go. Molding would cover the cut edges.

Comment: I second this, definitely don't build the wall right on top of the tiles. Use a chalk line to create a clean line to cut along with the angle grinder. Since the OP is talking about the possibility of shattering the tiles, it seems safe to assume they are stone or ceramic, not those thin composite tar-backed tiles (if it was those composite tiles, I might build right on top of them).

Comment: Yeah, I sorta figured that was the best solution, but I also figredit was a reasonable enough question to be worth asking. Excuse to get an angle grinder, perhaps, or some other high-speed cutter.

Comment: @keshlam If you use an angle grinder, make sure you keep the cut wet. Otherwise, you'll have a ton of dust. Also, wear a good tight fitting mask, or a respirator.

Comment: You'll love having an angle grinder... it's one of those tools I never thought would be a big deal, but I use mine very regularly. Don't waste time with regular masonry blades -- get a diamond blade. +1 to the point about dust... it's a pain, so tent, vacuum, water and do everything you can to keep the dust down.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that it depends a lot on the type of tiles. It they are a ceramic or stone tile then definitely remove then. I would say the same for any type of brittle old tile that would have a tendency to shatter if hammered on or having nails pounded into it.

Another consideration is the possible future replacement of the flooring. If it would end up being a major pain to trim the old flooring up to the base of the wall it is probably best to cut it now than to put it off to some future time.

Comment: Eventual replacement: Another good point. It isn't uncommon to put internal walls right over carpets, but it's alot easier to cut a carpet back to the wall.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you get the fastener through the tile and into your substrate (plywood or concrete) you should be fine.  Don't count on your tile to hold the wall.